# Why is the execution order not sequentyla in promises and await functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I have a code:

```
async function hh(){
    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {       
        resolve("First promise");
    });

    const promise2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        resolve("Second promise");
    });

    promise2.then((a)=>console.log(a));
    console.log(await promise1);
    console.log("sync call");
 }
hh();
```

result of this code is:

- Second promise
- First promise
- sync call

My first question why **sync call** is not on the first place?

Then I just deleted from the code **console.log(await promise1);**

So the code looks like this:

```
async function hh(){
    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {       
        resolve("First promise");
    });

    const promise2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        resolve("Second promise");
    });

    promise2.then((a)=>console.log(a));
    console.log("sync call");
 }
hh();
```

End result now is:

- sync call
- Second promise

So now sync call is on the first place, just beacuse I deleted the second call, why?

Comment: "*why sync call is not on the first place?*" - because the `console.log(await promise1);` comes before it in the code? That's the whole idea of using `await`!

Comment: Notice this is equivalent to `const result = await promise1; console.log(result); console.log("sync call");`. Surely you don't wonder why "*sync call*" is not logged first there?

Comment: You are not awaiting the `promise2.then((a)=>console.log(a));` but formally, it returns a promise. Just correct this with `await promise2.then((a)=>console.log(a));` and the behavior is consistent in both cases.

Comment: promise2.then((a)=>console.log(a)); is a microtask, it should come after the sync code

Comment: @GlebKrylov It's not synchronous code if you're doing some `await`ing it in. If you move the `console.log("sync call");` one line up, so that it happens right after the `promise2.then(…)`, you will get the expected result.

Comment: Also note, that instead of `console.log(await promise1);` you can introduce any `await`, `await 1` would do, just to create a point where the execution has to be terminated and continuted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens in that code:

### First version

`promise1` and `promise2` are promises in status fulfilled -- you could have used the `Promise.resolve` function instead of `new Promise`.

`promise2.then()` registers a callback to be executed when the promise is fulfilled, which it is, so the callback is enqueued as a job in the promise job queue.

`await promise1` suspends the `hh` function and registers `hh` to be resumed when the promise is fulfilled, which it is, so the resume of `hh` is enqueued as a job in the promise job queue (which now has two entries).

`hh()` returns a promise (that is ignored) and the JS call stack becomes empty. Now the event loop will extract the first job and execute it. This outputs "Second promise".

Then the call stack is empty again. The event loop will extract the last job and execute it. This resumes the `hh` execution context, which executes the `console.log` and outputs "First promise". It then continues with "sync call". Note that these two `console.log` are executed in one synchronous sequence, so there is absolutely no way that they could have their outputs in a different relative order.

### Second version

Here the `await` is missing, so there is no suspension of the `hh` execution context, and the promise job queue only has one entry.

As `hh` will run to completion the output "sync call" is the first output -- no job got a chance to run yet.

When `hh()` returns the JS event loop will pick up that one job and executes it. This is the callback that outputs "Second promise".

Answer (score 0):

### For the first question:

since `promise1` and `promise2` are resolved as soon as they are initialized, they will be in `resolved' state

in your code you call `promise2.then(a=> console.log(a))` i.e. `a=> console.log(a)` will be pushed to a (asynchronous) execution task (asynchronous by fulfilled) later when this string function is complete

but now all `hh` functions are waiting for `promise1<fulfilled>` to finish so the default `console.log(await promise1)` and `console.log('sync call')` will become default synchronous functions with `promise1`

ending `hh`

and the function `hh` ends the synchronous execution continue to execute the waiting tasks now because the `promise2` execution task added before it will be completely separated from the waiting task of `hh` it will be javascript executes because it is prepended resulting in the first function `a => console.log(a)` being executed
finish the task of `promise2` continue to `promise1` it works as synchronous code

#### Regarding the 2nd question

as I explained earlier `a => console.log(a)` is added to the task (asynchronously ready run by `fulfilled`) and `hh` does not depend on it leading to the next synchronous function continue executing `console.log('sync call')` then `hh` completes it continues executing `promise2` task
then you call `await promise1` it will also put the whole block of code afterwards (like you called `.then` above) into a task that executes (asynchronously)

> This is achieved because javascript is a single-threaded language:
>
> [https://dev.to/bbarbour/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd#:~:text=Javascript%20is%20a%20single%20threaded,times%20that%20can%20be%20harmful](https://dev.to/bbarbour/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd#:%7E:text=Javascript%20is%20a%20single%20threaded,times%20that%20can%20be%20harmful).

> you can also achieve the above by using asynchronous functions like `setTimeout`...

More information at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing

Comment: Not sure what "*will become default synchronous functions with promise1*" is supposed to mean. Also please use some punctuation to make your answer easier to read.

Comment: "then you call await promise1 it will also put the whole block of code afterwards (like you called .then above) into a task that executes (asynchronously)" — this is the most important part. Great answear!

Comment: @Bergi which means it's like normal synchronous functions you will have to wait for `promise1` task to complete (statements after await promise1 ) will be added to promise1's task as when calling `promise1.then()`

Answer (score 0):

Your promises are already resolved when your code reaches the last three operations. So, `.then()` is being called for `promise2` and that schedules it to be picked up by the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) once the current function is executed and this will happen under normal circumstances, this is why your second example first displays "sync call" and only then "Second Promise".

Yet, your `await` ensures that the current function is paused which allows the event loop to pick up the `.then()` of `promise2` and evaluate the results of `promise1`. If you invert the order of your first and second line of the last three, then you get "First promise", "Second promise" and "sync call" being displayed.

```js
async function hh(){
    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {  
        resolve("First promise");
    });

    const promise2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        resolve("Second promise");
    });

    console.log(await promise1);
    promise2.then((a)=>console.log(a));
    console.log("sync call");
 }
hh();
```

Comment: "*Since promise2 is a thenable object and the .then() is being called, it is resolved in your case*" - resolving promises with thenables is not happening here, I'm not sure how the mdn screenshot is relevant here?

Answer (score 0):

A simple conversion of your initial code block into code that doesn't use `async`/`await` probably shows why `console.log("sync call")` isn't executed first.

> ```
> async function hh(){
>     const promise1 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {       
>         resolve("First promise");
>     });
>
>     const promise2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
>         resolve("Second promise");
>     });
>
>     promise2.then((a)=>console.log(a));
>     console.log(await promise1);
>     console.log("sync call");
>  }
> hh();
> ```

```
function hh(){
    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {       
        resolve("First promise");
    });

    const promise2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        resolve("Second promise");
    });

    promise2.then((value) => console.log(value));

    return promise1.then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
        console.log("sync call");
    });
 }
hh();
```

The above should give you a clear picture of why `console.log("sync call")` is not logged first.

Everything after an `await` becomes part of a `then()` callback, since the function is paused until the promise resolves. Statements are executed in sequential order, so `console.log("sync call")` can only be executed after `console.log(await promise1)`.

```
console.log(a);
console.log(await promiseB);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
console.log(await promiseE);
console.log(f);
console.log(await promiseG);
```

Can be written as:

```
console.log(a);
promiseB.then((b) => {
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
  console.log(d);
  return promiseE;
}).then((e) => {
  console.log(e);
  console.log(f);
  return promiseG;
}).then((g) => {
  console.log(g);
});
```